# Узнать, какой ключ у определенного члена массива

Tags: php

Доброго всем дня

```
$php_array = array("a","b","c","d");
```

Есть массив. Можно узнать, есть ли определенный член в массиве (`in_array`). Но как узнать, какой ключ у определённого члена массива?

p.s. и тут сразу пошлёте меня в гугл за командой `array_flip`. Не катит! Да, конечно можно так. Но что, если в массиве значения длинные, да и, зачастую, содержат знаки, которые массивом не перевариваются? Вот и ищу рабочий вариант, побыстрее, чем перебор массива в цикле.

Comment: Что, если несколько одинаковых значений в массиве — какой ключ подавать?

    $dupes = array('c','c','c','p');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[array_search](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php)

> Осуществляет поиск данного значения в массиве и возвращает соответствующий ключ в случае удачи

Answer (score 2):

[array_keys()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-keys.php)

> Возвращает все или некоторое подмножество ключей массива